# Validate HWND using Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

From the native Win32 API using C++ is there a way to determine whether the window associated with an HWND is still valid?

Comment: [IsWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: As often happens, whether the window handle is valid or not has nothing to do with my particular problem.  Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use the Win32 API [IsWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528(VS.85).aspx).

**It is not recommended** to use it though for 2 reasons:

1. Windows handles can be re-used once the window is destroyed, so you don't know if you have a handle to an entirely different window or not.
2. The state could change directly after this call and you will think it is valid, but it may really not be valid.

From MSDN (same link as above):

> A thread should not use IsWindow for a
>   window that it did not create because
>   the window could be destroyed after
>   this function was called. Further,
>   because window handles are recycled
>   the handle could even point to a
>   different window.

**What can be done?**

Perhaps your problem can be re-architected so that you do not have the need to check for a valid handle.  Maybe for example you can establish a pipe from the client to the server.

You could also create a windows hook to detect when certain messages occur, but this is probably overkill for most needs.

Comment: What would be a solution then?

Comment: @Vlad: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Brian: to determine whether the window associated with an HWND is still valid?

Comment: @Vlad: I got that much, but I mean what do you want to do after that.  Also that's my point, once you know and you get to your next line of code, that assumption will already be broken because it may already be closed and a new one could even be opened.

Comment: It was worth a try, but the window owned by another process can still go invalid after the IsWindow call and cause a problem.  I will look for other solutions.

Comment: You need to know the behavior of the window in question.  Is this window running in the same thread as the function that is asking IsWindow?  If you can guarantee that the window cannot be closed while you're investigating its HWND, then you're okay.  If you cannot - truly independent threads, then you've a real design issue on your hands, and you need to rethink what you're trying to do (big picture), and rearchitect things so that you know when that HWND is valid due to the design of your software.

Comment: @Vlad: 1 - avoid storing window handles. 2 - if you must store a window handle, make sure you can invalidate that store when the WM_CLOSE or WM_DESTROY for the window occurs.

Comment: @Vlad and @Steve314: yes you could do this via Windows hooks for a different process, but there may be a simple solution to completely avoid this depending on the callers need.

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer to make those points.  Thanks @Vlad and @Steve314

Comment: @Brian: I understand that a window which I don't control myself can be destroyed even before the moment the stack is cleaned up after function call. But for me the correct answer to the question was interesting, not the reason why the question itself is "bad" (the latter I understand myself).

Comment: I didn't see Dougs comment before I wrote mine - should have refreshed. I still had the idea that it was inside one process. Since Brian found sense in it anyway, I'm half tempted to keep quiet, but I guess confession is good for the soul.

Answer (score 15):

This question is old, but I needed this functionality myself and was a bit disappointed after reading about the caveats.  However, after doing a bit more digging it seems that all is well.  Unless you're dealing with 16bit programs, IsWindow appears to be the way to go.  The problem of handle re-use appears to have been sufficiently addressed according to this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/17/3903614.aspx

So, because of the upper 16bit reuse counter, it is highly unlikely that you'll run into a window reuse problem.

Comment: You should really quote the point that is re-iterated in that article. "Behavior described here falls into the category of "implementation detail" and is subject to change at any time"

Comment: Good point.  Thanx.  I'm going to run tests myself to see if this implementation has changed.  I will say, however, that this is a fix that doesn't make sense to change.  Unless there is a good reason to reappropriate those upper 16 bits, I can't imagine that MS developers would want to cause themselves any greater headache than existed before the fix.

Comment: "Unlikely" is not the same as "impossible." The tagging in the upper bits is to mitigate a programming error. It is not something you should intentionally depend on.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [IsWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528%28VS.85%29.aspx) or also try to send the window a WM_NULL message with [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx)(hWnd, WM_NULL) and see if it is successful.

Also, it is true that the window could be destroyed at any time if it isn't under your control. As others have stated the handle could potentially belong to another window as the handles are reused. In reality I don't know how likely that is.

The only solution that I know of the to create a system wide [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx) that looks for messages indicating a window is destroyed (WM_CLOSE, WM_DESTROY). Then you would compare the message window handle to ones you are holding to see if any of the windows you care about are affected. [See here for more information on system wide hooks.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx)

Comment: Sending a WM_NULL message may not be a good idea.  Some apps actually perform operations in response to WM_NULL messages.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a combination of `IsWindow`, `FindWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` will be more accurate

```
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("window_title"));
LPDWORD oldpid = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, &oldpid);
//after some time
if (IsWindow(windowHandle))
{
    LPDWORD newpid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, &newpid);
    if (newpid == oldpid)
    {
        //the window is still running
    }else
    {
        //the window exists but has changed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the window procedure for the window in question is under your control (or if you can subclass it), then I would suggest registering a custom message that the window responds to with a non-zero result.  Sending that message to any other window (or an invalid HWND) will result in 0.

Of course, that only tells you if the HWND refers to one of the windows that you control -- but perhaps given other answers above that might even be advantageous.

Use RegisterWindowMessage to register the message, using a sufficiently unique name.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(IsWindow(FindWindow(NULL , TEXT("Example Window Name")))){
     // do stuff
 }
```

will check if the window exists and has the appropriate name