# How can I determent if a window still exists with a HWND

Tags: c++, windows, window, hwnd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate HWND using Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344233/validate-hwnd-using-win32-api)

How can I determent if the window of a HWND still exists? I have a HWND of a window. The window exists in another process. I want to know if the Window is still “alive”. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN `IsWindow` function is doing exactly this:

> Determines whether the specified window handle identifies an existing window.